# How do I run an OS X app built with xCode to see if dependencies work

Tags: xcode, macos, deployment, xcode4

I am working on an OS X app in xCode, and I was wondering what the easiest way was to test the app in a "clean" environment without all of my developer's frameworks. I need to know if the app will work AS IS on other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do for my own projects is I have a second hard drive attached to my Macintosh on which I have installed various (clean) versions of MacOS with no Xcode or extra frameworks hidden in /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib, etc.

That way you can try your app out in a relatively clean environment, and if your app writes lots of files or installs things in System places, it's easy to reinstall MacOS and get a pristine set-up again without messing up your main development hard drives.

Comment: I was wondering if that is what I would have to do. I wish there was an easier way to do it on one machine, but oh well. Thanks!